# How can I find the IP address of IP Cam on network using android programatically

Tags: java, android, xml, router, ip-camera

I need the IP address and port no of IP cam which connected on router. You already know most of the IP Cam have admin,password and Device ID.

I know the Device ID, admin and password, I am not much familiar with java/android. If anyone share me the tutorial/blog or code snippet of java and xml with explicitly add permissions

**NOTE:** Assume android device and IP Cam connected on same router (local network)

**NOTE:** I have Chinese manufacture IP Cam. Here is the link of product.
[Product link](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Bulb-Light-Wireless-IP-Camera-Wi_60663341431.html?spm=a2700.7724857.normalList.11.42f666e2TL2QqE&s=p)

I know many App available for this purpose but my goal is to learn and doing something else.

Answer (score 0):

You could ping all possible adresses to list all adresses that respond and then get their hostname to match it with your device ID.'

Code example :

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;

public class HostFinder {
    private static int ADDR_MAX = 256;

    private List<InetAddress> reachableAdresses; 
    private String hostname;
    private CyclicBarrier cb;

    public HostFinder(String hostname){
        this.reachableAdresses = Collection.synchronizedArrayList();
    }

    public void find(Handler handler, String hostname){

        // Building possible adresses
        InetAddress localhost = InetAdress.getByName("localhost");
        String[] splitAddr = localhost.toString().split(".");
        String root = splitAddr[0] + "." + splitAddr[1] + "." + splitAddr[2];

        // Callback action when the treahd finishes
        this.cb = new CyclicBarrier(ADDR_MAX, () -> {
            for(InetAddress addr: reachableAdresses){
                if(addr.getHostName().equals(hostname)){
                    handler.handle(add);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });

        // Launching a thread that will ping each address possible on the local network
        for(int i = 0; i < ADDR_MAX; ++i) {
            Thread t = new Thread( () -> {
                InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(root + "." + i);
                if(addr.isReachable(5000)){
                    reachableAdresses.add(addr);
                }
                else{
                    try {
                        this.cbr.await();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        System.out.println("Thread error");
                    } 
                }
            });
            t.start();
        }
    }

    // Async handler to fetch the data
    public interface Handler{
        public void handle(InetAddress addr);
    }
}
```

Comment: I need this on android using programmatically, can you share me the code snippet ?

Comment: I added a code example to asynchronously ping all possible addresses on the network and match their hostname

Comment: Thank you for your help but how can I execute this code. I have no foundation in java programming. Can you please elaborate your code So I test this code in my eclipse IDE.

Comment: Just create the class I provided I your IDE, create a main an call the find method with the hostname you want to find